# Read div element

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have defined `sap.m.Button` is SAP UI5 view, when I see Elements tab in developer tool then element looks like below

```html
<div class="sapUiVltCell sapuiVltCell">
  <button id="Submit" data-sap-ui="Submit" class="sapMBtn sapMBtnBase">
    <span id="Submit-inner" class="sapMBtnDefault sapMBtnInner sapMBtnText sapMFocusable">
       <span class="sapMBtnContent" id="Submit-content">
         <bdi id="Submit-BDI-content">Submit</bdi>
      </span>
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

When I capture click on button using DOM element `onClick` function, I see that `Event.target.id` has `id="Submit-BDI-content"` which is last element of div node instead of id `Submit`.

I need div ID of button element `Submit` not `Submit-BDI-content`

I know parent element can be read using `document.getElementById("Submit-BDI-content").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode` but I don't want to use it as I want to write generic logic. In this example there are two span elements but it is possible that another button do not have any span element.

I am looking for a logic which can give me div ID element of the clicked element.

Can someone please suggest?

Comment: for what purpose do you need the div? there is probably a UI5 way to achieve your requirement without manipulating the DOM elements directly...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JQuery

```
$("#Submit").click(function(){
    alert("button");
});
```

or why capture DOM element click function, you can use press property to define function caalled on clicking button.

```
<Button text="Click Me" press="onclickFn" ></Button>
```

In controller -

```
onclickFn : function(){

//body of click function

}
```

Comment: My requirement is different. I do not want to capture event in Controller file. I want to capture using DOM element